# How to replace constant by monkeypatch

Tags: python, pytest, monkeypatching

I want to mock(override) constant in my test.

- constants.py

```py
LIMIT = 1000
```

- my_class.py

```py
from constants import LIMIT


class MyClass:
    def get_limit(self):
        return LIMIT
```

- tests/test_my_class.py

```py
from my_class import MyClass


class TestMyClass:
    def test_get_limit_should_return_value(self, monkeypatch):
        monkeypatch.setattr('constants', LIMIT, 10)
        c = MyClass()
        assert c.get_limit() == 10
```

This result is following.

```sh
$ pytest
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform linux -- Python 3.8.0, pytest-6.2.4, py-1.10.0, pluggy-0.13.1
rootdir: /home/sugimurase/src
collected 1 item                                                               
tests/test_my_class.py F                                                 [100%]
=================================== FAILURES ===================================
________________ TestMyClass.test_get_limit_should_return_value ________________
self = <test_my_class.TestMyClass object at 0x7f83b54c4940>
monkeypatch = <_pytest.monkeypatch.MonkeyPatch object at 0x7f83b54c4d00>
    def test_get_limit_should_return_value(self, monkeypatch):
>       monkeypatch.setattr('constants', LIMIT, 100)
E       NameError: name 'LIMIT' is not defined
tests/test_my_class.py:6: NameError
=========================== short test summary info ============================
FAILED tests/test_my_class.py::TestMyClass::test_get_limit_should_return_value
============================== 1 failed in 0.08s ===============================
```

I replaced 'constants' to 'my_class.constants', 'MyClass', but got same error.
How can I do this?

Comment: if you have already imported the `MyClass` in your test, that means you the import of `LIMIT` was executed at that time too, so monkeypatching it in constant won't help.  You should monkeypatch the method `get_limit()` itself.

Comment: I didn't fully understand where the constants would be active. Your advice was very helpful. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to monkey patch `LIMIT` on `my_class`. To do this import `my_class` and make sure you pass the *string* `"LIMIT"` and the *name* `my_class` to monkey patch (You have that backward above). This passes for me:

```
import my_class


class TestMyClass:
    def test_get_limit_should_return_value(self, monkeypatch):
        monkeypatch.setattr(my_class, 'LIMIT', 10)
        c = my_class.MyClass()
        assert c.get_limit() == 10
```